# PDF and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What problems can arise when users hits the get_pdf action?
If there are problems, how can it be solved?

```
class PdfController < ApplicationController
  def get_pdf
    send_data Pdf.create(params[:contents])
  end
end

class Pdf
  def self.create(contents)
    make_pdf(contents) # takes 30 seconds to run
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The major problem is that typically you will have a limited number of Rails processes on your server, and every time a user makes a request he occupies an entire Rails process for the duration of the request.

Let's say you have 8 rails processes.  If eight users request a PDF at the same time, the processes will all be occupied for 30 seconds and no one else can use your site for 30 seconds.

If you look in to it a little deeper you'll find that actually the down time will be a bit longer than 30 seconds because Rails has to spend time sending the file to the user and the user might have a slow internet connection.  You might be able to get around this if you enable the right kind of buffering in your web server or use something like nginx's [X-Accel-Redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile).

Another problem is that whatever web server you are running might give up on the request after it decides Rails has waited too long.  It probably won't give up after just 30 seconds, but maybe you should check your web server configuration just to be sure.

You should also be sure to provide the correct HTTP headers to tell the browser what kind of file this is.  I think `Content-Type` is what you need.